# Rails 2.1 to_json with include and methods throwing argument error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a rails 2.1 app with order which belongs to group.
I want to return the order with json, include the group (specifically only one table column), and some methods for the order.

I have this code in my show method:

```
@order = Order.find(params[:id])   
render :json => @order.to_json(:include => { :group => { :only => :article_cap }}, :methods => [:fee, :get_url], :only => [:id, :group_id])
```

Before, I didn't need the group, and using just 'methods' and 'only' worked fine. Now I need to 'include' the group, and I get this error:

> ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)):
>   /home/name/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352@code/gems/activerecord-2.1.0/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:177:in `get_url'
>
> ...

It works fine if I do only the include, or only the methods, but not if I do both at once. Any ideas?

EDIT: I see now that it is trying to call get_url on the associated, included group model (it has the same method as order, but requires passing something to it). I thought you would have to write it as:

```
:include => { :group => { :methods => :get_url } }
```

for this problem. I can't seem to get it to include the method from the @order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thinking for a second as to what rails is trying to do (access a method on an included model instead of the primary model), I realized all I needed to do was add some methods for the included model (even if I add nothing at all). Check this out:

```
render :json => @order.to_json(
  :methods => [:get_url, :link_expired, etc...],
  :include => { :group => { :methods => [], :only => :article_cap }},
  :only => [:id, :group_id]
)
```

I added an empty array of methods for the included group, and rails figured out that the methods I was adding must not be for group. I have not seen this mentioned anywhere, which is weird that no one had this problem; perhaps it's the expected behavior. Hopefully this helps someone else!

Comment: I'm not sure, I haven't gotten the chance to use 4 yet.